# Bash- add up two arrays variables' to third array's variable

Tags: linux, arrays, bash

i have three `arrays A, B, C`. Array A-B values are being parsed from file and i want them to add up into `array C`.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
A=()
B=()
C=()
while read line
do
  A[i]="$(echo $line| cut -d\  -f4)"
  B[i]="$(echo $line| cut -d\  -f11)"
  echo ${A[i]} " and " ${B[i]}
  # outputs correct values
  C[i]=`expr ${A[i]} + ${B[i]}`
  echo ${C[i]} 
  # no output
  i=$((i+1))
done < ~/file
exit 0
```

what is wrong with that assignment?

complete line from script:

```
hitEnd[i]=`expr ${hitLength[i]}+${hitStart[i]}`
echo "${hitEnd[i]}"
#no output
```

Comment: Could you paste the complete error output?

Comment: @louxiu complete error output: ./getSum.sh line 131: 635: command not found.. (635 is the array B's value)

Comment: @louxiu at the first `echo` it outputs the correct values, but at the error output there is no value shown for array A's value..

Comment: No idea... what about paste the input file?

Comment: Please paste an exact copy of line 131 of the script.

Comment: @Barmar hitEnd[i]=`expr ${hitLength[i]}+${hitStart[i]}`

Comment: Paste it into the question so it's formatted properly.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I ran your script and it worked as expected. There must be something in the real script that you're not showing.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, i can not believe how stupid i am :(.. i was incrementing $i before i output the C[i].. so it is now confirmed that i am stupid or blind..

Comment: That explains the "no output", but not the error message.

Comment: @Barmar what should i do with the question? delete or something??

Comment: BTW, using `echo | cut` is an expensive way to get the 4th and 11th fields on the line. Why not do `read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 rest`, then use `$f4` and `$f11`?

Comment: You could request deletion, or just wait for it to be closed as too localized.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, in fact i am reading only first two columns of the file, i just wrote the example in a rush. but i did not know that using cut is expensive compared to your suggestion. can `read` discriminate the delimiters?

Comment: You can set the variable `IFS` to specify the delimiters used by `read`, normally it uses any whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

the line:

```
    C[i]=`expr ${A[i]} + ${B[i]}`
```

while give an error if one of the two operands is missing.
If that is expected, i.e. having empty fields in the files, then:

```
   C[i]=$((${A[i]:-0}+${B[i]:-0}))
```

Should work.

Answer (score -1):

The script look correctly. You may not construct the array correctly.

And always double quote the variable to avoid some error.